# ora-12560: TNS Protocol Adapter Error

Tags: sql, oracle10g, ora-12560

I am dead stuck with this - the ora-12560. I tried to check the Services.msc and all the oracle are already running.

[image]

[image]

I can Login in Toad though but not using the command prompt.
Please help me.

Comment: What environment and registry settings do you have? Are ORACLE_SID or LOCAL set, and if so to valid values? What about ORACLE_HOME? SQL\*Plus doesn't usually go through TNS unless you specify an alias or connect string with `@`, but will do if LOCAL (TWO_TASK in Unix) is set. How are you connecting from Toad?

Comment: Thank you very much for these useful info, Alex :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. Somehow the Path was changed. So i put it back to its previous path and now i can connect. :)